# jQuery (document).ready not waiting for DOM to be ready

Tags: jquery, dom

I've got a very subtle animation in the header. When first loading the page, or refreshing with cmd+shift+r (mac) to clear the cache, jQuery really doesn't seem to wait for the DOM to be ready. It starts the animation before all the normal html/css has popped up.

Am I just misunderstanding exactly what (document).ready actually does?

Comment: What version of jquery are you running?  There were some issues in 1.8 that cause the ready to fire too early.  http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12282

Comment: I assumed he wasn't using IE due to the mac keyboard shortcut, though i may be wrong.

Comment: Reading the [jQuery documentation on .ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) should clear up what it does and when it is called.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DOMContentLoaded fires when the DOM is ready, but that doesn't necessarily mean all of the CSS and Images are done loading. If you want that, a better option would be `$(window).on('load',function(){...});`